# Как работает асинхронный неблокирующий ввод-вывод на уровне ядра ОС?

Tags: linux, многопоточность, ос, kernel

Читаю как работают асинхронные вызовы

> Системные вызовы (system calls) – это интерфейс между операционной
> системной (ОС)  и пользовательской программой. Они создают, удаляют и
> используют различные объекты. Пользовательская программа запрашивает
> сервис у ОС, осуществляя системный вызов. При системном вызове задача
> переходит в привилегированный режим или режим ядра (kernel mode).
>
> Асинхронный системный вызов не приводит к переводу процесса в режим
> ожидания после выполнения некоторых начальных системных действий,
> например запуска операции вывода-вывода, управление возвращается
> прикладному процессу.

1. Не совсем понятно когда у меня поток запросил асинхронный ввод вывод и как бы перешел в режим ядра, как он потом дальше продолжает работу, в обычном режиме? Т.е. если у меня отправлен асинхронный системный вызов из потока, а дальше делается еще какая то логика то в этот момент времени у меня как бы будут работать 2 моих потока, один в режиме ядра получать данные, а другой в обычном режиме работать параллельно как обычные потоки чередуясь?
2. Допустим у меня есть 3 потока в которых я хочу прочитать 3 разных файла, причем первый существенно больше двух других.
   Первый поток отправляет в ОС системный вызов на чтение данных с диска и останавливается на их ожидании, второй поток запрашивает чтение с диска и останавливается на их ожидании, третий тоже запрашивает и останавливается. Получается на уровне ОС у меня будет как бы 6 потоков?
   Три будут ждать окончания операции чтения от ОС, а три будут реально считывать данные с диска параллельно чередуясь как обычные потоки, чередуясь ?

Например

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/file.md', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
moreWork(); // функция будет исполнена до console.log
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135479/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Резюмирую, когда у меня идет мой поток и видит системный вызов он переходит в режим ядра, раздает команды нужным устройтсвам откуда что он хочет получить и куда это положить, и возвращается обратно в пользовательский режим выполнять код дальше если есть, и когда вернется ответ от ОС что данные готовы поток вернется в нужное место доделать работу, примерно так ?

Comment: Похоже на правду. Но не видно, что было до этого - сообщения просто удалили

Comment: @KoVadim, не удалили, а перенесли в чат ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ну а я о чем? когда поисковиком ищешь, то он никогда не показывает чат, а значит, знания утеряны. Я знаю, что администрация сайта думает по другому, но для меня перенос в чат - это просто удаление полезной информации.